# Is it possible to interact with cloned iOS simulators via xcrun simctl?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode-ui-testing, xcrun, simctl

When I'm running UI tests in parallel on multiple simulators, the cloned simulators appear to be totally invisible to `xcrun simctl`.

When running `xcrun simctl list`, the source simulator appears, but is in a "shutdown" state:

`4 Inch Snapshots - en-US (0) (3334A5D1-A4EC-41ED-AB10-55495B4BE329) (Shutdown)`

And when I try to run any commands againts "booted" devices, it claims there are no simulators running:

```
xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "2007-01-09T09:41:00-05:00"
No devices are booted.
```

Is there any way to target these cloned simulators with `xcrun simctl`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you mean the clones that are managed by Xcode's  Testing, you can do:

```
xcrun simctl --set testing ...
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for! Is there any documentation for `--set` anywhere? I see ` [--set <path>]` listed when I run `xcrun simctl help`, but can't find any reference to how to actually use it.

Comment: You just pass it a path, and it will use that path for your set of devices.  It supports aliases for well-known sets (eg "testing" is ~/Library/Developer/XCTestDevices)